# Ansible - vars are not correctly propagated to handlers when role run in loop

Tags: ansible

I am asking for help with a problem of deploying multiple versions (different variables) of the app with the same role run from one playbook.

We have an app with multiple product families, which are different code versions. Each version has separate uWSGI vassal config and Nginx virtualhost config(/api/v2, /api/v3, ...).

The desired state would be to run playbook and configure the server with all versions specified.

Sadly, ansible's `import_role/import_tasks` can't be used with `with_items`, so `include_role/include_tasks` must be used (pitty because they do not honor role tags).

The `include_role` method would not be the biggest problem, but we use handlers to notify **uWSGI touch to reload** - on a code change, link change, virtualenv change, app_config change, ...).
But when using loop (`with_items`), the variables passed from the loop does not correctly propagate to **handlers**.

I tried this scenarios

#### playbook.yml - with_items loop inside the playbook

PROBLEM: Handler is run only for the first iteration of the loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook

# HAndler is run only once, from first notifier
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    app_root: "/tmp/test_ansible"
    app_versions:
      - app_product_family: 1
        app_release: "v1.0.2"
      - app_product_family: 3
        app_release: "v4.0.7"
  tasks:
   - name: Deploy multiple versions of app
     include_role:
       name: app
     with_items: "{{ app_versions }}"
     loop_control:
       loop_var: app_version
     vars:
       app_product_family: "{{ app_version.app_product_family }}"
       app_release: "{{ app_version.app_release }}"
     tags:
       - app
       - app_debug
```

#### playbook_v2.yml - with_items loop inside role task

PROBLEM: Handler is run with the default value from "Defaults"

```
#!/usr/bin/env ansible-playbook

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  roles:
    - app_v2
  vars:
    app_v2_root: "/tmp/test_ansible_v2"
    app_v2_versions:
      - app_v2_product_family: 1
        app_v2_release: "v1.0.2"
      - app_v2_product_family: 3
        app_v2_release: "v4.0.7"
```

Tasks `roles/app_v2/main.yml`

```
---
# Workaround because import_tasks can't be run with_items
- include_tasks: deploy.yml
  when: app_v2_versions
  with_items: "{{ app_v2_versions }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: app_v2
  vars:
    app_v2_product_family: "{{ app_v2.app_v2_product_family }}"
    app_v2_release: "{{ app_v2.app_v2_release }}"
  tags:
    - app_v2
    - app_v2_deploy
...
```

---

One idea was about writing a separate role for each product family, but they share **nginx** and **uWSGI**, so it will be lots of copy-pasting and sharing tasks (so tags would not work properly).
For now, I solved it with shell script wrapper, but this is not an ideal solution and does not work from Ansible tower.

[Sample repo](https://github.com/mmitucha/ansible_with_items_handlers) with tasks to reproduce problem (tested with ansible 2.4, 2.5, 2.6)

Any ideas & recommendations are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of overrides for variables is broken for includes in Ansible. F.e. even `set_fact` in the included role will be shadowed by role defaults.

See this bug: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/22025

It's closed but not fixed. My advice: use include and variables really carefully.

In practice I never use role includes with loop. If you need loop, include a tasklist in this loop (and that tasklist, in turn, may `import_role`).

Comment: I think I found this bug while trying a workaround - setting the variable using `set_fact` inside tasks. I was surprised that it was not propagated.  

I know that what I am trying to do is not a super elegant way, but I wanted to use group_vars and host_vars, so no need to hardcode all the plays with the variables for every region separately. So I assumed someone must have run into this and solve it somehow.

Thank you very much for help George.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It is a bug as @George Shuklin posted.

I will use my shell wrapper, which reads group_vars yaml and then runs the playbook multiple times according to the variable list length.

Sadly I hit multiple annoying bugs in ansible in last few weeks, kinda losing my trust in it ):

And probably everybody is using microservices and kubernetes, so need to speed up our migration (: